# Windows 10: How To Turn Off The Error Sound On A Failed Auto Complete?

Tags: windows-10, audio, notifications

**Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise**

When you try an autocomplete in a shell, on Windows 10, where there is no completion Windows 10 plays a harp/chiming sound.

I would like to turn that off.

I found a dialog by clicking the sound icon in the Task Bar that has a long list of sounds and events to turn off.   The problem is that the names of the events aren't descriptive.

Does anyone know the name of the event I described?

Comment: try "asterisk". IIRC that is the default windows shell alert when something related to input doesn't work right. its been a long time, but thats where I'd start

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows *System Sounds* CPL, use the *►Test* button to preview sounds.

[image: Preview Sound]

- Start an application that has the *Autocomplete* feature.
- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type *sou* and select *Change system sounds*.
- Select a sound.
- Click on *►Test* button.
- When you find the correct sound, select the first item, *(none)*, in the *Sounds* drop-down list of files to eliminate it.
- Test *Autocomplete* to see if that is the correct sound.